# Как осуществить Insert запрос в hibernate,передав getter?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, h2

Когда я пользвался jdbc template,вопросов не возникало,я просто пользовался такой конструкцией:  public void add(Info Info) {

```
        final String sql = "INSERT INTO info (name,memory,id,type) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, Info.getName(), Info.getMemory(), Info.getId(), Info.getType());}
```

Но с переходом на hibernate у меня возникли некоторые трудности с синтаксисом,помогите осуществить эту же операцию,пожалуйста.
Пробовал так:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public void add(Info info) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("insert into Info(id,name,memory,type)" +
            "select  info.getId,info.getName,info.getMemory,info.getType from Info");
    int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Ничего не вышло:

Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [info.getId], unexpected token [info] [insert into Info(id,name,memory,type)select info.getId,info.getName,info.getMemory,info.getType from spring.example.model.Info]

Ниже привожу сам класс:

public class Info  {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
@Column(name = "MEMORY")
private Integer memory;
@Column(name = "TYPE")
private String type;


public Info() {
}
```

Дальше идут геттеры и сеттеры

Comment: *Ничего не вышло* обычно сопровождается сообщением об ошибке. Где оно? А так ежели - то после сложения строк между закрывающей скобкой и последующим select не наблюдается ни одного пробела... Ну и - в таблице Info, если верить коду класса, нет полей, перечисленных в предложении select.

Comment: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [info.getId], unexpected token [info] [insert into Info(id,name,memory,type)select info.getId,info.getName,info.getMemory,info.getType from spring.example.model.Info]

Comment: Добавляйте важную информацию в текст вопроса. а не в комментарий.

Comment: session.save(info) не пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Answer (score -1):

Может кому-то сохранит два дня жизни) `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public void add(Info info) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query insertQuery = session.createSQLQuery("" + "INSERT INTO INFO(id,name,memory,type)VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
        insertQuery.setParameter(1, info.getId());
        insertQuery.setParameter(2, info.getName());
        insertQuery.setParameter(3, info.getMemory());
        insertQuery.setParameter(4, info.getType());
        insertQuery.executeUpdate();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }`